# priority queue insertion

Tags: c, priority-queue

Im working on a method for insertion into priority queue using the huffman method. However I keep getting the same error:

```
     prioque.c:46: error: expected ")" before "prioque_ref"
```

my structures are:

```
typedef struct prioque *prioque_ref;
struct prioque {
    int dim;
    int last;
    prioque_item *array;
    cmpfn_prioque cmpfn;
};
```

my code in question:

```
void insert_prioque (prioque prioque_ref *queue, prioque_item item) {
    assert ( queue->last < queue->dim -1);

    ++queue->last;
    queue->array[queue->last] = item;
    int curr = last;

    while (curr != ROOT) {
        int parent = PARENT(curr);
        int *parentptr = &queue->array[parent];
        int *curptr = &queue->array[curr];

        if (*parentptr > *currptr)
            break;

        int tmp = *currptr;
        *currptr = *parentptr;
        *parentptr = tmp;
        curr = parent;
    }

    DEBUGF ('p', "queue=%p, item=%p\n", queue, item);
}
```

What am i doing wrong here??

Comment: So, you are saying that you don't have a `;` after `typedef struct prioque *prioque_ref`? If so, then that's your first error. If you do have `;` there then, please, *post real code*, not "something I think is right".

Comment: You have a couple good answers here already, but for future reference it's easier for us to help if you tell us which line is line 46.

Comment: Sorry! Line 46 is the first line of my insert method, I will definitely keep that in mind for future reference and thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already done a typedef for `prioque *`

```
void insert_prioque (prioque prioque_ref *queue, prioque_item item)
                         // ^ complaining about this space
```

So, it should be -

```
void insert_prioque (prioque_ref queue, prioque_item item) { /* .... */ }
```

Comment: perfect! that and a few other misc tweeks seemed to to the trick. Much thanks!

Comment: @KufNayr - As @Karl suggest, do also say through a comment in the code itself mentioning where that specific line exists. Glad that it worked :)